# Scrolling Textbox Content Overflows into padding area

Tags: padding, expression-web, vertical-scrolling

How can I stop my scroll bar and the text when scrolled from appearing in my top padding area. I am new to Microsoft Expression Web and CSS and I am very frusterated with this.

Here's what I have so far but as mentioned above the text still wants to scroll into the top 75px of padding as well as the scroll bar is permantly displayed through this top padding.

```
width: 210px;
float: left;
height: 220px;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 75px;
padding-left: 35px:
```

Answer (score 0):

try playing with the "overflow" setting.  First try replacing "auto" with "scroll."  If you don't want the scroll bar (I'm a bit confused by your question) change "auto" to "hidden."

Let me know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry won't let me add a comment to poindexter's suggestion comment is as follows:

Thanks for your suggestions but changing the overflow to scroll gives me a horizontal and a vertical bar when I only want a vertical bar. "Auto" was doing this correctly. I'll try to explain a bit more my issue.

In order for my text to be positioned correctly within the page I have had to create padding in the top and left side. This moves the text lower in the page and to the right. Problem being that the scroll bar when it appears goes above where the text starts and into the padding. Once you scroll through the text, the text you have already looked at also goes into the padding area and disappears when it reaches the top of the div. Hope that makes more sense. The website isn't live or I would refer you to it for a visual.